# what's type for data in success: function(data)?

Tags: php, jquery

Here $fruit is encoded by js_encode() and send back to data in ajax. My questions is what datatype of data is(string or array)?
Thanks in advance!

```
$.ajax({
                                type:"post",
                                dataType:"json",

                                url:"phpFile.php",
                                success: function(data) {


                                }
                          });

<?php
    $fruits = array(array("1","apple"),array("2","pear"));
    echo js_encode($fruits);
?>
```

Comment: I think you mean to use json_encode($fruits), unless you have written a function called js_encode.

Answer (score 3):

You specified the data type of the response as `json`. jQuery will try to automatically decode the data as JSON and pass the resulting JavaScript data type to the callback. So `data` can be either a <del>*string*, *number*, *boolean*, *`null`*,</del> *array* or *object*.

In your specific case, you are encoding a PHP array as JSON, so the result will be an array.

Comment: If you parse a JSON string you can only have an array or an object. The other data types can be represented inside, but the outer most data type can only be array or object.

Comment: @Quentin: Mmh, you are right... I swear I've seen jsonlint declaring  `"somestring"` to be valid JSON, but now it dosen't... strange. Imo `JSON.stringify("foo")` should fail then though as well...

Comment: Perhaps a bug in jsonlint that is now fixed?

Answer (score 2):

It won't be anything. The success method will never fire because the PHP will error with `Fatal error: Call to undefined function js_encode()`, which will return a 500 error, so jQuery will fire the `error` function (if it existed) and not the `success` function.

If you were to fix the PHP and use `json_encode`, then it would output a JSON with a top level array, so `data` would be an array.

Note that you should also make sure that your script doesn't claim the JSON is HTML.

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

Answer (score 0):

`data` variable will contain the following: 
`[["1","apple"],["2","pear"]]`